# what type of list does FindElements(ByTagName("a")) returns?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, java, xpath

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Automation Stuff/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ArrayList<WebElement> links = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        ***links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));***

    }

}
```

I'm new to automation, just wanted to know why driver.FindElement(ByTagName("a")) is not storing the results in ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add elements to `ArrayList` from a function `driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"))` that returns object type `List`.

Every `ArrayList` is a `List`, but not every `List` is an `ArrayList`.

`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

`ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Try Using

```
List links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for(WebElement link : links)
{

  System.out.print(link.getAttribute("href"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since findElements uses WebDriver as generic type, List is an optimum choice.

```
findElements(By by)
Find all elements within the current context using the given mechanism.
java.util.List<WebElement>
```

findElements()

1. On Zero Match : return an empty list
2. On One Match : returns list of one WebElement only
3. On more than One Match : returns list with all matching instance

Comment: what is the exact difference between ArrayList and list ?

Comment: List is a more abstract version of ArrayList. like Animal is a more abstract version of Dog, Cat etc

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Selenium in Java but I think that the return type is `List<WebElement>`

Use:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements
```

or convert ArrayList to List